# errors when trying to tweet using tweepy

Tags: performance, authentication, permissions, tweepy

I am working on an academic research project and I am trying to send out tweets using the the Twitter API. The error I am receiving repeatedly is

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
Your client app is not configured with the appropriate oauth1 app permissions for this endpoint.
```

```
import tweepy

#from tweepy import OAuthHandler

ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'


api = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='xxx',
                    access_token=ACCESS_KEY,
                    access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET,
                    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)


api.create_tweet(text='I want to Tweet')
```

Here is my code. The authentication raises no errors. Just the attempt at tweeting.

Answer (score 25):

You can fix the problem by activating Read / Write in the Oauth section of your application, and then you shall regenerate the "Access Token and Secret".

You can check that are properly recreated when you see:

*Created with Read and Write permissions*

EDIT as of 10/February/2023: You are now required to ask for Elevated access if you want to have read + write permission. You only have read access from the V2 API Endpoints as of today

Comment: How do you ask for elevated access?

Comment: nvm, I found it under settings > User authentication settings

Comment: I had activated the Read / Write but did not regenerate the tokens which left me confused for some time, but your post helped me, thank you!

Comment: thanks for adding to regenerate the tokens. fixed my problem :)

Comment: after i regenerated the access tokens, i started getting Unauthorized, any idea what happened?

Comment: Hi @bobmason, we lack some information about the issue, but I would guess you are still using the old token in the code instead of the new one you regenerated

Comment: @EnricFontSegarra Thank you, i have resolved it, since the whole thing was confusing when regenerating new keys, some old data was still in the app, never mind it's how they like to complicate things.