# Free Twitter API, forbidden/unauthorized errors when trying to use tweepy

Tags: authentication, permissions, tweepy

I'm trying to do anything at all with Twitter API v2, with not much success so far.

```
import tweepy
Client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="...", consumer_secret="...", access_token="...",
                       access_token_secret="...", wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

This code raises no errors, so authentication appears to be successful. Now I try to retrieve the list of followers:

```
followers = []
for item in tweepy.Cursor(Client.get_users_followers("...")).items():
    followers.append(item._json)
```

That results in an error:

```
Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

When attempting to create a tweet:

```
Client.create_tweet(text="Python test.")
```

That also results in an error:

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
Your client app is not configured with the appropriate oauth1 app permissions for this endpoint.
```

It appears that it was possible in the past to resolve the "Forbidden" error [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436471/errors-when-trying-to-tweet-using-tweepy) way (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095257/using-twython-to-send-a-tweet-twitter-api-error/19196583#19196583) way, though I think it's the exact same thing), but the edit in the former post states that "You are now required to ask for Elevated access if you want to have read + write permission. You only have read access from the V2 API Endpoints as of today". I tried to find out online what the elevated access is, and if [this post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-do-i-apply-for-elevated-access/190797) is to be believed, it is no longer a thing, and now the only option is buying Basic for a $100/month.

So my questions are:

1. is it true that since recently the only way of getting writing privileges is buying a subscription, and otherwise Twitter API is strictly read-only?
2. even so, retrieving the list of followers is a read-only command. And yet for whatever reason it also results in the "Unauthorized" error. Is there any way to get the list of followers without paying for the subscription?